# does linkedin's people search API returns same results for different access tokens?

Tags: api, search, linkedin-api

I am using multiple access tokens to search people on linkedin. I would like to know if same set of people is returned, when First Name and Last Name is provided, regardless of access token that I use for searching that particular person? And if so, does the result set remain exactly the same (e.g preserving the order of people in the result set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The linkedin API for people-search returns the same set of people in the same order, for different access tokens.